# Simple Ruby Command Line Question

Tags: ruby

Um - I feel like an idiot, but....

```
ruby -e '3+5'
```

Outputs nothing (Windows 7, Ruby 1.8.7, Cygwin or Git Bash). What am I missing? Extra credit - will this also allow the extra cool bundle (stolen from TextMate) Execute and Update # => markers to work properly?

**EDIT**

Ok that worked, and I'll accept the answer, but e-texteditor still doesn't work with that really cool bundle. Too bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

> ruby -e 'puts 3+5'

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a call to puts or any other method that produces output. `ruby -e` doesn't print the return value of the expression - it just executes it. It acts exactly as if you were executing a rb file containing "3+5".